# Creating multidimensional array from existing arrays with variable variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a class function which accepts a mysql query result and returns a multidimensional array where the first array pointer is the table column and the second pointer is a numeric indicator of its position in the MySQL data.

Eg the table has the following columns:

```
Groupname
Groupid
Groupurl
```

And the way I want to call this is:

```
$arrayname[groupname][1];
```

I have formed 2 arrays already which are:

`$colnames` which contains all columns from the specific mysql query and

`$$colname` which is a variable variable of the column name containing all the data in each column. Eg: `$groupurl` is an array with all the data from that column.

I can't seem to get a loop to join the arrays as a multidimensional object and while I can manually do this for a specific table, it's a class function, and the variable variable part is breaking me =\

================ Thanks to IMSoP who gave me the idea, the solution is ==================

$result in the function is a successful MySQL Query on a table.

```
function tableAsMatrix($result)
{
    //declare $results as array for use in loop
    $results = array();

    //this gets all the col names and sets them as $colnames[]
    while( $cols = $result->fetch_field() )
    {
        $colnames[] = $cols->name;
    }

    //this loops through and assigns all cols as multidimensional $results[colname][id]
    foreach ($colnames as $fields)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
           foreach($colnames as $field)
           {
               $results[$field][] = $row[$field];
           }
        }
    }

    //return to object
    return $results;

}
```

Comment: Where does the "variable variable" `$$colname` come from? Why can you not simply populate `$return[$colname]` as you go along?

Comment: Thanks to IMSoP, who gave me the idea, Ive come up with the following in the original post!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Other than choosing the array type, everything else is mysqli OO based, you just cant see the rest of the class. The code has been fixed. Im not sure where you got the idea from that it was or was not mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I used is:

```
function tableAsMatrix($result)
{
    //declare $results as array for use in loop
    $results = array();

    //this gets all the col names and sets them as $colnames[]
    while( $cols = $result->fetch_field() )
    {
        $colnames[] = $cols->name;
    }

    //this loops through and assigns all cols as multidimensional $results[colname][id]
    foreach ($colnames as $fields)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
           foreach($colnames as $field)
           {
               $results[$field][] = $row[$field];
           }
        }
    }

    //return to object
    return $results;

}
```